# Using max-age in cookies nodejs using res.setheader

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am testing nodejs..

I am using Express.

I want to make a cookie.

the way I know is-

```
const express =  require("express");
var app =  express();

app.get("/set-cookie",(req,res)=>{
   res.setHeader("set-cookie", "value=true");
});
```

I want to make a cookie using `res.setHeader()` with the max-age set to 1 minute ***without adding more dependencies***

I have tried

```
const express =  require("express");
var app =  express();

app.get("/set-cookie",(req,res)=>{
   res.setHeader("set-cookie", "value=true;MaxAge="1000*60");
});
```

But it is not setting the max-age to one minute.

What should I do?

Comment: `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'value=true;Max-Age=60');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`res.cookie`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) method to set the maxAge, below code will return a cookie which expires in 1 minute:

```
app.get("/set-cookie",(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('cookieName', "value", { maxAge: 60*1000 });
    res.send();
});
```

If you're using plain [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) (`setHeader`) you must keep in mind that:

> Max-Age= Optional
> Number of seconds until the cookie expires. A zero or negative number will expire the cookie immediately. If both Expires and Max-Age are set, Max-Age has precedence.

so your code should look like this:

```
app.get("/set-cookie",(req,res)=>{
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "key=value; Max-Age=60");
    res.send();
});
```

Comment: +1 for differentiating between `res.cookie` and `res.setHeader`. I was providing the number of seconds without multiplying by `1000` for `res.cookie` and it was logging out faster than expected.